# Timer and TimerTask Problem: "Timer.class not in android.jar" and "The Application Has Stopped Unexpectedly"?

Tags: java, android, timer, timertask

So I'm trying to make a "live feed" essentially, and my code is shown below. Basically, I got "The Application Has Stopped Unexpectedly" error, so I debugged. When I debugged, it said "Timer.class not in android.jar". I know my refreshFeed() static method works perfectly fine (tested it without the timer), so it can't be that. Is there something I'm missing here? Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
Timer time = new Timer();
    TimerTask refresh = new TimerTask(){
        public void run(){
            feedEntry.refreshFeed();
        }
    };
    time.scheduleAtFixedRate(refresh, 0, 10000);
```

Comment: which Timer class are you using?

Comment: David I was and am using the Timer class from java.util

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both Timer and TimerTask present in java.util package.

What you need to is do is use handler.
Read about handler if you are new to android. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

```
Handler handler = new Handler();


    t = new Timer();
    timeTask = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            feedEntry.refreshFeed();
                        }
               });
        }};

        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(timeTask, 0, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks HellBoy! Worked like a charm! :-)